# Set image in other layout in android

Tags: java, android

I run on `MainActivity` and I have `firstshow.xml` with image `imageView` (`imshow`) and I use `Inflater` to show it on dialog with this code

```
ImageView fistTimeImv =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imshow);
        fistTimeImv.setImageResource(R.drawable.first1);
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this);
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
        final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.firstshow, null);
        dialog.setView(view);
        dialog.show();
```

The above code throws `NullPointerException` in the following line

```
 fistTimeImv.setImageResource(R.drawable.first1);
```

Comment: Where you are initializing `fistTimeImv` ?

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly you want to inflate a `View` from xml and set that `View` on a `Dialog` but you are getting a `NullPointerException` when attempting to do so.  To fix that you have to reorder your code as the following:

```
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
    final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.firstshow, null);
    ImageView fistTimeImv =(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imshow); //Make sure to call findViewById on the view you just inflated
    fistTimeImv.setImageResource(R.drawable.first1);
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setView(view);
    dialog.show();
```

There are two changes here: The first change is inflating your `view` before finding the `ImageView`. If your `ImageView` is a child element of your `firstshow` layout then that layout needs to be inflated (built) first. The second change is making sure that you try to find your `ImageView` from the newly inflated `view`. If you don't have `view.findViewById(R.id.imshow);` you will try to find the `ImageView` on whatever `class` you are currently working in which probably isn't what you want.